# Optimal Design for MongoDB database

Tags: .net, mongodb, nosql

I'm developing an application for storing form content.  There could be potentially millions of records for each form.

My backend is .NET / MongoDB.  I've currently implemented the following design but am not sure that its the most effective solution for this quantity of content.

```
[{
     formId: '12344',
     records: [ { id: '12444543', customerName: 'Panda Express', ... } ]
}, ...]
```

The number of top level 'forms' won't be more than 20 in most cases with the records for each form in between 1,000 and a million.  The number of attributes in each 'record' won't be more than 100 in most cases.

Is this the most effective way to do this in mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this is not the best design. Storing records in a single document is not a good idea if your document growing fast. Since maximum BSON document size is 16MB, this could cause problems when you have millions of records.

Instead you can store records seperately as follows.

record collection :

```
id: '12444543', 
formId : '12345',
customerName: 'Panda Express', 
...
```

Comment: Thats how I started but thought the filtering on form id might be better.  If this is optimal I'm in favor of this for simplicity too!

Comment: Since you said you have at most 20 forms, second option might be to store records of each form in a separate collection. This will save you from filtering by formId.